# How to make a timer trigger when you click a button?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, timer

I am working on a Windows Form Application, making a button to show another form and I am trying to make the user wait some time after he clicks the button and after the time passes then the form will open.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Timer1.Start() 
End Sub 

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick 
    Timer1.Stop() 
    Form3.Show() 
    Me.Hide() 
End Sub
```

When I use the code above, `Form3` is shown before I even click the button.

Comment: if this is a Winforms app, the CSS and (html) FORMS tags are inappropriate.  Otherwise show the code you have tried so far

Comment: What is the interval on your timer?

Comment: 4000 milliseconds  , basically I want the timer to start when I click the button.

Comment: Do you receive any kind of error or exception with that code?

Comment: No , the only problem is that the timer starts before I click the button.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that you set the `Enabled` property on the `Timer1` component to `False` in the form designer.